# What is parameter sniffing in Stored Procedure? How you will overcome that?

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please help me to understand what is paramenter sniffing in Stored procedure in SQL server along with a wonderful example? And also how we can overcome this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you read, what didn't you understand?